# How can I see folders from terminal?

Tags: command-line

How can I list folders from within the terminal, which command should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to distinguish folders from files easily, use something like `ls -alhF`. I usually define `l` as an alias for that, ie. I put the line `alias l='ls -alhF'` in my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 33):

to list only folders try: `ls -d */`

---

### Explanation

#### `-d`

> list directories themselves, not their contents.  To explain this, consider what happens if we type `ls */`.  `ls` goes one layer down, into each subdirectory, and lists all the files in each of those sequentially

<sup>Source: `man ls`</sup>

#### `*/`

`*/` is known as a "glob" in UNIX.  (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) for more details).  But basically, it means "any file name ending in a forward slash."  In UNIX, directories are really just files, fundamentally.  But they are specially named ending in a forward slash so the operating system knows they are directories (or folders, in everyday-person-speak).  And the asterisk `*` is technically a wildcard standing for "any string of characters."

#### What is a glob?

This paragraph will not pertain specifically to *your* question, but if you've never read about this, it'll be good to see it.  Globs are different from Regular Expressions, as (partially) explained in [What is the difference between Regular Expressions and Globbing?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-expressions-and-globbing-828589/)  There have been whole books written on regular expressions, but tl;dr there are a bunch of different ways to encode pattern-matching expressions.

Comment: How to show hidden folders as well? ls -d .*/ shows only hidden folders. How to view BOTH hidden and non-hidden folders? I can only think of ls -d */ .*/ Anything better?

Comment: well, you can try ls -la | grep ^d but it is much longer :)

Answer (score 7):

As I am a very inexperienced user I love [this](http://ss64.com/bash/) website.
It tells you all you want to know about bash commands, in some cases it even gives you examples. Very useful.

In your case:

- `ls` to list the files
- `ls -a` to include hidden files
- `ls -l` for a long listing format
- ...

Answer (score 6):

```
ls -1 -d */
```

where

`-1`

lists one directory per line.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -al | grep ^d
```

include hidden files '-a' 
grep ^d get start with 'd' wich means directory
when name starts with dot directory is hidden

to list recursively see this

```
find ./ -type d | less
./ ..................... means starts find in current folder
-type .................. indicates the type to be searched
d ...................... means directory
| ...................... redirects the command
less ................... enables paging using the keyboard arrows and leave with q
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To view home directory folders the `ls` command is enough - this will keep it simple.

   ```
   $ ls

   Desktop    Downloads         hadoop  Pictures  Templates
   Documents  examples.desktop  Music   Public    Videos
   ```
2. You can even specify multiple directories `ls ~ /usr`

   ```
   $ ls ~ /usr

   /home/hadoop1:
   Desktop    Downloads         hadoop  Pictures  Templates
   Documents  examples.desktop  Music   Public    Videos

   /usr:
   bin  games  include  lib  local  locale  sbin  share  src
   ```
3. To get the output in long format we can use the `-l` option

   ```
   $ ls -l
   total 48
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Desktop
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Documents
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Downloads
   -rw-r--r--  1 hadoop1 hadoop1 8980 Jul  1  2017 examples.desktop
   drwxr-xr-x 10 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 hadoop
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Music
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Pictures
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Public
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Templates
   drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop1 hadoop1 4096 Jul  1  2017 Videos
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`ls` will list the files.

`ls -l` will list the files with details (such as file size).